# HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR value not found - PHP

Tags: php, http, proxy

I have set Proxy in my browser and when i echo

> $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']

in one of my site i am not getting  value,  but with the same settings in browser from another site i am getting value

How i could get the value of

> $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']

when i am using proxy. Whether i need to enable anything in my server